# query object in multidimensional array that does not exist

Tags: ruby, hash

I have this array:

```
--- !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
search: !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
  address: test
```

I apply the following to it:

```
address = params['search']['address']
if address
  # do something
end
```

If there is no search object and no address object, this code raises an error:

> You have a nil object when you didn't
>   expect it! You might have expected an
>   instance of Array. The error occurred
>   while evaluating nil.[]

What's the way in ruby to handle something like that?

Comment: As Jits points out, you probably have an array. Comment in ruby is not `//`, it's `#`. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly...

> [...] for example i have this array:

Just to clarify that it is actually a specialised `Hash`.

Secondly...

You can do something like this:

```rb
if params[:search] and params[:search][:address]
  # do something with address
else
  # no value given
end
```

Comment: thanks, you're right. why is `params['search']['address']` working for a hash?

Comment: @choise, it's a special kind of hash that can take strings or symbols as keys and treat them as the same.